# Pandas not exporting dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a script to output a whole bunch of CSVs to folder c:\Scripts\CSV.  This particular script is looping through all of the dataframes and counting the usage of the top 100 words in the data set.  The top 100 words and their count are added to a list, the dataframes are concatenated, and then the csv should export.  The print contains the correct information, but the script doesn't output any file.

```
#! python3
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r'Scripts\\CSV\\'
directory = os.path.join("c:\\",path)
appended_data = []

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
     for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            thread = pd.read_csv(directory + file)
            thread.columns = ['num', 'id', 'body', 'title', 'url']
            s = pd.Series(''.join(thread['body']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:100]
            appended_data.append(s)
thatdata = pd.concat(appended_data)
#print(appended_data)
thatdata.to_csv = (directory + 'somename.csv')
```

Comment: `thatdata.to_csv(os.path.join(directory, 'somename.csv'))`

Comment: Try to debug it yourself, add print statements to print the exact pathname before the `to_csv()`, tell us what you found out.

Comment: You don't want the `=` in your `to_csv` line; you're overriding the _method itself_, not calling it.  Should we close this as a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to debug it myself, I initially had it like :
    thatdata.to_csv(directory + 'somename.csv')
and it was not outputting.  The solution I recieved from sacul fixed my issue and made me feel like a noob, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pathlib` instead:

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
directory = PureWindowsPath('c:/Scripts/CSV/')
for csv_f in directory.glob('**/*.csv'):
    # process inputs
target_path = directory / 'somename.csv'
thatdata.to_csv(target_path)
```